# HTACCESS many directories with rewrite base, rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a serious problem which is the next :
I have a directory like this : http://example.com/kl/bold2/bold3/contents/
what I would like to do is to make is a rewrite, for example I have :

http://example.com/kl/bold2/bold3/contents/menu.php?menu=herewego

and I would like to transfer it to this :

http://example.com/herewego

So, guys how can I do this with htaccess ?

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 0):

you should put something in url that Apache can decide which rule should apply! otherwise it's impossible to rewrite URL with correct rule!
for example :http://example.com/longdir/herewego

```
RewriteRule ^longdir/(.*)$  kl/bold2/bold3/contents/menu.php?menu=$1
```

Comment: Hello,
So, I can't do like this : example.com/hereweogo ?
There is website like bit.ly or google url shortner in which you can see like this : goo.gl/8H3L9 
Do you have another idea to develop it more ?
Thank you !

Comment: @Hamza if you do that there is no other way to distinguish between other rule! but if there is no other rule you can do it!